# Compiler error when Calling a generic method with no actual argument but with explicit type parameter

Tags: java, generics, language-design

From the book "Java Generic and Collections", section 1.4 there is this code sniplet

```
class Lists {
    public static <T> List<T> toList(T... arr) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T elt : arr)
            list.add(elt);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then there is this statement:

> When a type parameter is passed to a generic method invocation, it
>   appears in angle brackets to the left, just as in the method
>   declaration. The Java grammar requires that type parameters may appear
>   only in method invocations that use a dotted form. Even if the method
>   toList is defined in the same class that invokes the code, we cannot
>   shorten it as follows:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> ints = <Integer>toList(); // compile-time error
> ```
>
> This is illegal because it will confuse the parser.

So I am trying to understand why there would be compiler-time error.

Comment: This is not how such method should be called Leon

Comment: Change line 6 by: Integer result = HelloWorld.foo();
Generic type is determined by the declaring data type, in this case integer.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin `foo` is declared `void` not `Integer`

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. I assumed this: `static <T> T foo(final T... arr) { }`

Comment: This is my "homework" ;=) I am looking at book "Java Generics and Collections" by O'reilly.  I have updated the original question how I came to it.

Answer (score 0):

> So I am trying to understand why there would be compiler-time error.

Because that's to [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). See [JLS §15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#20448):

> A method invocation expression is used to invoke a class or instance
>   method.
>
> ```
> MethodInvocation:
>       MethodName ( ArgumentListopt )
>       Primary . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
>       super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
>       ClassName . super . NonWildTypeArgumentsopt Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
>       TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
> ```

As to why the specification was written that way, only the language designers can answer that.

Comment: The question is really why the specification specifies this way for the generic method invocation.