# How to pass the result of calling a statically imported generic method to another method?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I have a simple function B.init:

p/B.java

```
package p;
import java.util.*;
public class B {
    public static <T> List<T> init(int n) {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
        while (n --> 0) l.add(null);
        return l;
    }
}
```

A.java

```
import p.B;
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(B.<String>init(5));
    }
    public static void f(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("l: " + l);
    }
}
```

It works as expected:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
l: [null, null, null, null, null]
```

But I want to import `p.B.init` statically:

```
import static p.B.init;
import java.util.*;
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(<String>init(5));
    }
    public static void f(List<String> l) {
        System.out.println("l: " + l);
    }
}
```

It fails to compile:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:5: illegal start of expression
        f(<String>init(5));
                  ^
A.java:5: ';' expected
        f(<String>init(5));
                      ^
A.java:5: not a statement
        f(<String>init(5));
                       ^
A.java:5: ';' expected
        f(<String>init(5));
                        ^
4 errors
```

Why? Is there no way to call a static generic function without importing the class and prefixing it by the class name? I know you can change it to:

```
        List<String> l = init(5);
        f(l);
```

but I don't want to introduce another variable. You can also do it by casting (`f((List<String>)(Object)init(5));`) but this causes compiler warnings.

Simply removing the `<String>` before init causes this error (I asked why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262199/cant-pass-the-result-of-a-generic-method-to-another-method)):

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:5: f(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) in A cannot be applied to (java.util.List<java.lang.Object>)
        f(init(5));
        ^
1 error
```

Comment: To make it simpler try calling the equivalent of `f(<String>init(5))` from inside `B` - are you sure it's a static import problem.

Comment: @selig yep it happens then too, so it must not be because of static imports

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082519/compiler-error-when-calling-a-generic-method-with-no-actual-argument-but-with-ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax in Java to specify the type arguments of a method at the call site without qualifying the method call with its containing class or instance. Note that this has nothing to do with static imports. For example, look at this code:

```
<T> void x(T x) {}
void y() { this.<Object>x(""); }
```

No static methods involved at all, but the issue is the same: in this case you cannot avoid the explicit `this`.